# ADO.NET connection problems need ODBC?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, odbc

I want to implement a data migration from MySQL to SQL Server with ASP.NET 2.0 (C # 3.5)
for now the connections to the MySQL database are made using ODBC, I want to change this by using ASP.NET with SQL Server and using technology that gives me as LINQ.

The problem is I can not connect (`web.config`)

Provider tells me I need to register my SQL ODBC ADO.NET knew not need an ODBC mushroom bad my provider or me? Need an ODBC ADO.NET? if so how I can use LINQ to SQL?

I test my apliacion locally and works but to deploy the server is down

The error message I get is the following:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   Establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server or not was found
>   not was accessible. Verify That the instance name is correct and That
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server / Instance
>   Specified)

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall. It seems you cant connect to SQL from your server. Install SQL management studio as a test to see if you can even contact the SQL box.

Comment: the problem is server side, as my supplier suggests using ODBC and I want to use ADO.NET to use dotNET tenologias that gives me as LINQ to SQL